# Configure Python Selenium Proxy

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can i configure my proxy username and password on my script. At the moment its currently prompting me enter login details every time i run chromedriver

```
                webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
                    "noProxy":None,
                    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
                    "sslProxy":'192.168.1.1:80',
                    "httpsProxy":'192.168.1.1:80',
                    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
                    "autodetect":False
                }
```